# VB2010 Unable to open two applications derived from same code at the same time

Tags: vb.net, winforms

This may be a simple question, but I'm not even sure of the search terms to find the answer.

I have two winforms applications which have been derived from the same code. One supersedes the other, but occasionally we have to us the older VB app for legacy information.

The problem is, if one app is already open, when the icon of the other app is clicked, nothing happens. The currently open app's window becomes selected like it has just been opened. Nothing else.

What I would like to happen is that both apps can open at the same time. They reference different DB's so there's not clash there.

I thought it might be something to do with the name spaces, so I changed those, but to no avail.

Any thoughts, I'm sure its a simple answer.

Mark

Comment: Somewhere in project settings, you can select 'allow only one instance open' or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Project Settings (Double Click on "My Project" in the Project Explorer).
In the Application-Tab you'll find the setting "Create Single Instance Application"
(I'm translating from German Version, may be slighlty different).

**Better Alternative**:
Basicly it is useful to keep this setting as it is and go for the alternative:
In that same spot, you find a button "Assembly Information". Click on that and change the first number of the "Assembly Version". Now the older and newer versions are two different programs for Windows and will run parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Go to, 'project properties', Tab 'Application', section 'Windows application framework properties'.  There is a checkbox called 'Make single instance application'. Maybe that's on...

Comment: thanks! thats worked. however, it also feels like a workaround. I wonder what can i change so windows sees the apps the as two separate entities. Anyway, its still worked, so great!

Comment: No, its the otherway round, by default, you allowed to start your app more times. A developer of this project decided in the past to have it run only once. Prolly to avoid pll clicking/starting it twice...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with two applications. They had different assembly versions and I wanted to avoid unchecking "Make single instance application", so I kept looking until I found that they had the same GUID. Just changed one of them and problem solved. You can change the GUID in the Assembly Information dialog. Hope it helps.